# Get page html in Java from specific url that needs Cookie

Tags: java, html, cookies

I am trying to get the html source of

> https://www.coinbet24.com/en/odds/football/algeria/ligue-1

In general, I have done this tons of times, and never had a problem, yet this specific website is giving me a hard time.

No matter what I try, I get a response with populated head, but an empty body.

The only time that it works and I actually get the full response, is if I manually set the Cookie in the request header to be equal to the Cookie of my actual browser.

I tried automating this process by first getting the connection headers and setting the Cookie through those, but once again, I am getting a blank body.

This is how I get the Cookie, then set it for the request. I also tried with Apache HttpClient. Same result.

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36");
Map<String, List<String>> headers = connection.getHeaderFields();
connection = url.openConnection();
String cookie =
  headers.get("Set-Cookie").get(0).split(";")[0] + "; " + headers.get("Set-Cookie").get(1).split(";" + "")[0];
System.out.println("cookie = " + cookie);
connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36");
connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String str;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(str);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.